# Reduce ResultIterable objects after groupByKey in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on temperature forecasting data using PySpark.

The raw temperature data in the following format:

```
station;date;time,temperature;quality
102170;2012-11-01;06:00:00;6.8;G
102185;2012-11-02;06:00:00;5.8;G
102170;2013-11-01;18:00:00;2.8;G
102185;2013-11-01;18:00:00;7.8;G
```

The target result is getting the min/max temperature for each year, mentioned in which station, like the following:

```
year;station;max_temp
2013;102185;7.8
2012;102170;6.8
```

My current code as the following:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="maxMin")
lines = sc.textFile('data/temperature-readings.csv')
lines = lines.map(lambda a: a.split(";"))
lines = lines.filter(lambda x: int(x[1][0:4]) >= 1950 and int(x[1][0:4]) <= 2014)
temperatures = lines.map(lambda x: (x[1][0:4], (x[0], float(x[3]))))
```

so far, the result as following:

```
temperatures.take(4)

(2012, (102170,6.8))
(2012, (102185,5.8))
(2013, (102170,2.8))
(2013, (102185,7.8))
```

After grouping by key, the becomes as the following:

```
temperatures = temperatures.groupByKey()
temperatures.take(2)

[(u'2012', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x2a0be50>), 
(u'2013', <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable object at 0x2a0bc50>)]
```

So, how I can reduce these resultiterable objects to get only the element with min or max temperature.

Comment: is there a reason for using `rdd`'s instead of `DataFrame`'s?

Comment: Do you think it will make a difference?

Answer (score 4):

Just don't. Use reduce by key:

```
lines.map(lambda x: (x[1][0:4], (x[0], float(x[3])))).map(lambda x: (x, x)) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (
        min(x[0], y[0], key=lambda x: x[1]), 
        max(x[1], y[1], , key=lambda x: x[1])))
```